# ExtJs (Version 7.4) : Tree Panel -> on Click of each parent node proxy URL gets called from store

Tags: extjs

I am building a Tree Panel using Extjs.
Trying to load dynamic children data from proxy URL.
Data gets loaded to the Store and also the tree panel gets displayed, but  on click of parent node proxy URL gets called again and again and tree gets reloaded.
I have even mentioned the leaf value as true for children and false for the the parent nodes but still the same issue occurs.
Also I have given expanded:false for root node but still it gets automatically expanded.

Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Comment: Fiddle sample will be very useful.

Comment: @ArthurRubens: Thanks for your prompt response.
Issue was with my JSON response.
I have changed the response and its working as expected.